# SQL grouping with two tables

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

1I have the following two tables (sample data) and need to be able to group the all the `id`'s which belong to the larger group called `code` and `dateCreated`, group when the dates are the same for the `code`

table1:

```
dateCreated | id
2011-12-27  | 1
2011-12-15  | 2
2011-12-17  | 6
2011-12-26  | 15
2011-12-15  | 18
2011-12-07  | 22
2011-12-09  | 23
2011-12-27  | 24
```

table2:

```
  code      | id
    EFG     | 1
    ABC     | 2
    BCD     | 6
    BCD     | 15
    ABC     | 18
    BCD     | 22
    EFG     | 23
    EFG     | 24
```

So the results (Hopefully right) should I need would be where codes are grouped by date:

```
dateCreated | code
2011-12-27  | EFG
2011-12-15  | ABC
2011-12-17  | BCD
2011-12-26  | BCD
2011-12-07  | BCD
2011-12-09  | EFG
```

Hopefully this makes sense....

I've tried a few things most recent something like this but without any luck (invalid column GroupCodes)

```
select dateCreated, (SELECT  distinct  code
                     FROM  table2 INNER JOIN
                     table1 ON id = table2.id) as GroupCodes

from table1
group by dateCreated, GroupCodes
```

Comment: Why would you `group` if you're not adding any aggregate function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe I'm missing the issue, but wouldn't the following work?

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    t1.dateCreated, t2.code
FROM
    table1 t1 JOIN
    table2 t2 ON t1.id = t2.id
```

Comment: Yep it must have been a long day as this is all that's required for this part of my query (thanks I'll mark it right when it allows me to)